# Case between two unrelated types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems

Is it possible to use `case` expression between two unrelated types in Haskell, like in this example (not working) code:

```
data A = A
data B = B

f x = case x of
  A -> 1
  B -> 2

main = do
  print $ test A
  return ()
```

I know I can use `Either` here, but this code is not meant to be used - I want to deeply learn the Haskell type system and see what could be done.

Comment: Ask yourself: What would be the type of `x`?

Comment: @delan - this is exactly the question I'm trying to answer - I was thinking that maybe there is some Haskell extension or feature I don't yet know, which would allow me to do that kind of stuff :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`A` and `B` are distinct types. If you want a function that can take values of multiple types, you need a typeclass.

```
data A = A
data B = B

class F a where
  f :: a -> Int

instance F A where
  f _ = 1

instance F B where
  f _ = 2

main = do
  print $ f A
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible with a normal case statement, but you can hack this sort of thing using type classes:

```
data A = A
data B = B

class Test a where
    test :: a -> Int

instance Test A where test = const 1
instance Test B where test = const 2

main = print $ test A
```

But you should only use this if it's *really* required, as it gets messy very soon and you end up with needing a lots of extensions to the type system (UndecidableInstances, OverlappingInstances, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing your own type class for f, you could use the Typeable
class which has some support by ghc. You don't need to use Dynamic here, but in
some cases it is needed.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Dynamic

data A = A deriving (Typeable)
data B = B deriving (Typeable)

f x | Just A <- fromDynamic x = 1
    | Just B <- fromDynamic x = 2

f2 x | Just A <- cast x = 1
     | Just B <- cast x = 2

main = do
  print $ f (toDyn A)
  print $ f2 A
```